# How should I use the question "or am I?" and what does it express?

Tags: question-tags

I've seen it many times, but I just don't get it.

> I am a good student, or am I?
>
> I am not a good student, or am I not?
>
> I am a good student, or am I not?
>
> I am not a good student, or am I?

1) Which of those examples above are correct?

2) What's the use of this kind of question?

3) Is it simply rhetorical as I see it?

4) What's its structure meant to be like? (g.e: aff sentence - aff question?)

5) What's the intention of the speaker with this kind of question?

6) What's the listener's interpretetion of it?

Comment: It's not clear what your fundamental question is, but "or am I not" must be used with great care to be meaningful -- it's not used correctly in the above examples.

Comment: I only recognise 'or am I' as usable in those examples.  I have never seen, "or am I not" in that context. (EDIT I see that Hot Licks has already said that)

Comment: So, please @HotLicks and chasly from UK, enlighten me on this one. Because I just don't understand this kind of question... I don't even know how to use it.

Comment: In those uses, "or am I?" is a quasi-dialogical method of raising doubt and thus creating suspense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a good student, or am I?
>
> I am not a good student, or am I?

In those examples you have a statement followed by an expression of doubt. If we remove the conjunction and use separate sentences, you can see this.

I am a good student, or am I? ---> I am a good student. Am I a good student?

I am not a good student, or am I? ---> I am not a good student. Am I a good student?

It doesn't matter whether the statement part is affirmative or not. The question part is simply a question.

**Usage**

The most likely usage is to challenge an accepted view.  Example:

A: Should we promote John to store manager?

B: Well we all know that John is not a suitable candidate, or is he? In fact, in the last couple of months he has improved enormously. I think we should give him a chance. Perhaps we could promote him on a trial basis.